# Geometrical approach , angle in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $z$ lies on the circle $|z-2i|=2\sqrt{2}$, then the value of $\arg(\dfrac{z-2}{z+2})=? $

My approach:

I tried to solve this problem by algebraic way and got the equation of circle as- $x^2+(y−2)^2=8.$  Solving the complex number, I got my argument to be $45^\circ$. But I was wondering if there is a geometrical approach considering the complex number lies on a circle.

Comment: Why does it only have one value as an argument? You are talking about points on a circle. You could reformulate the quotient such that only the numerator remains a complex number which would still indicate a collection of points on a circle with center at (2,2) and radius $sqrt{8}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found the right circle. Note that the quotient we seek is $\frac{z-2}{z-(-2)}$. This is the angle between the line joining $z$ and $2$, and the line joining $z$ and $-2$. Now, all three points, $z$, $-2$ and $2$, lie on the circumference of the circle, and the two lines in question form an inscribed angle. Recall that the measure of an inscribed angle is $\frac12$ the measure of the central angle subtending the same arc. The central angle, in this case, is part of the triangle with vertices $-2,2,2i$. This is an isosceles right triangle, with right angle at $2i$. That means that the inscribed angle is half of a right angle.

Note that this theorem only applies in this way in the case where $\mathfrak{Im}(z)>0$. Otherwise, the angle is either undefined (if $z=\pm 2$), or else equal to $-\frac{3\pi}{4}$, or $-135^\circ$ (if $\mathfrak{Im}(z)<0$).

Comment: For simple complex numbers like 3+4i,the argument gives us the anticlockwise angle with the x axis preferably in the range of -(-π to π) but in these cases like arg(z-2)-arg(z+2),will this  represent difference of the angles the lines make with positive x axis?

Answer (score 1):

The circle passes through $2$ and $-2$. So the required argument value is the angle subtended by the chord joining $2$ and $-2$ on the circumference of the triangle. The angle subtended at the center $2i$ is $\pi/2$. Hence the answer will be $\pi/4$.